# MacBook Air Header Identification

Tags: connector, header

Simple question: **Can someone please help me identify this header type on my MacBook Air's (i7 A1369) motherboard.** Bottom line is a series of unfortunate events 
have led me to have to reset the the chip that stores the EFI firmware password, and this header allows access to it - but I need to make a connector/adaptor.

I know iPhones use this type of connector, but if someone could put a name to it, that would be fantastic. Cheers! (photos below).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to measure the dimensions and pin spacing for yourself, but once you have those, what you're looking for is a board-to-board connector commonly called a mezzanine connector.

Here is a link to Digi-Key to get you started on your search.

[Mezzanine connectors on Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine/1442154?k=mezzanine%20connector&k=&pkeyword=mezzanine%20connector&FV=1600014%2C1680002%2Cfff40016%2Cfff8016a%2C1140003&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)

Comment: Sweet man! Obviously the pin pitch and number vary, but does the height/depth?

Comment: It might vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, but I wouldn't expect there to be different versions of the same part with different depths. I could be wring though.